# Separate PDF output of Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

My problem is as follows:

```
% File name: Example.tex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}    
\begin{document}
\cite{key}
\bibliographystyle{IEEETran}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

I want to generate the reference file in a separate PDF output. I can either run the standalone `Example.bbl` file as input or add the code as suggested below. I want to get the an additional PDF file for example `Reference.pdf` as an output each time. `Example.pdf` also contains the reference as a main file.

Comment: You stand better chances of getting an answer that helps you if you can give more details about your current approach. There are many ways to create bibliographies in TeX and a solution will quite heavily depend on the one you use. A convenient way to give that information is an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) it is a very simplified version of the code you use that others can still compile.

Comment: @moewe Added MWE with a specific doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simplified version for `bibtex` that writes a file at the end and does automatically compile it at the end. The external file is called `\jobnamesepbib.tex`, e.g. `foosepbib.tex`.

It's possible to include the `.bbl` file in a 'standalone' document. However, special packages etc. needed must be included in the file writing too.

However, the `bibtex` step must be done outside. Compile as usual three times.

This does not work for `biblatex`, however.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \newwrite\bibstuff

    \AtEndDocument{%
      \immediate\openout\bibstuff=\jobname sepbib.tex
      \immediate\write\bibstuff{%
      \string\documentclass{article}^^J
      \string\begin{document}^^J
        \string\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.bbl}{}{}^^J
        \string\end{document}^^J
      }
      \immediate\closeout\bibstuff
      \immediate\write18{pdflatex \jobname sepbib.tex} % Compilation
    }

    \begin{document}
    \section{Foo}
    \nocite{*}

    \bibliographystyle{alpha}
    \bibliography{references}




    \end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}

\newwrite\bibstuff

\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\openout\bibstuff=\jobname sepbib.tex
\immediate\write\bibstuff{%
  \string\documentclass{IEEEtran}^^J
  \string\usepackage{cite}^^J
  \string\begin{document}^^J
    \string\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.bbl}{}{}^^J
    \string\end{document}^^J
}
\immediate\closeout\bibstuff

\immediate\write18{pdflatex \jobname sepbib.tex}
}


\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\cite{knuth1986texbook}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{references}


\end{document}
```

Here's my standard `references.bib` for TeX.SX`:

```
@book{knuth1986texbook,
  keywords = {book},
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Bibby, D.},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley}
}
@article{knuth1977fast,
  keywords = {article},
  title={Fast pattern matching in strings},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Morris Jr, J.H. and Pratt, V.R.},
  journal={SIAM journal on computing},
  volume={6},
  number={2},
  pages={323--350},
  year={1977},
  publisher={SIAM}
}
```

Comment: Don't know why I am getting error! I will try to solve it, otherwise I will post the results here.

Comment: @Mithun: See the update please

Comment: I run the code, however, can't able to find the reference PDF file. May be I did something wrong again.  I am not clear `\immediate\openout\bibstuff=\jobname sepbib.tex` and `\jobname.bbl`. Do I have to change it according to my Tex file name as Example.tex and Example.bbl? And what will be the output PDF file name?

Comment: It will be called `Examplesepbib.pdf` then and be placed in your working directory.

Comment: One step ahead. I got the Examplesepbib.tex file that contains `\documentclass{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{cite}
 \begin{document}
 \InputIfFileExists{Example.bbl}{}{}
 \end{document}`. I understand that we create another file. Good. However, still I am not getting PDF file directly. I have to run `Examplesepbib.tex` file for PDF. Is there any problem with my pdflatex while running `\immediate\write18{pdflatex \jobname sepbib.tex`? Anyway, it serves my purpose.

Comment: @Mithun: Apparently, your `shell-enabled` is not activated.

Comment: I correct pdflatex as `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` in Texstudio. Succeed. :)