# Compile LaTeX file to produce main document and references as separate files using BibLaTeX/Biber

Tags: biblatex, luatex

I am using the BibLaTeX package, with the Biber backend for producing a proposal for a grant. However this grant agency (like a few others) requires a separate file for the main proposal and the references. I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301492/69936), but it is quite old and uses BibTeX. I scanned through the [BibLaTeX documentation](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), and did not find a command for producing the bibliography as a separate file. I know I can use two `.tex` files, with the second one producing the references from the `.bbl` intermediary file (as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3334/69936)), however, I would like to have both in one step, as my professor is rather touchy about using LaTeX in the first place. Also, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3337/69936) provides a bash script to split the file, which won't work on my professor's Windows machine.

So, is there a cross-platform way using BibLaTeX/Biber to automatically split the document such that the references end up in a separate pdf, at each build using LuaTeX?

---

### MWE:

File `biblio.bib`

```
@article{key1,
  title={Paper Title},
  author={Author, Author},
  journal={Some Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={143--154},
  year={2001}
}
```

File `proposal.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4j,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=10, uniquelist=false, backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\title{PROJECT DESCRIPTION}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle

  Some text with a reference to \citet{key1}. The bibliography should actually be output to a separate pdf file.

  % Commenting next line to prevent references from appearing in the main document
  %\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: See Ulrike Fischer's answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files

Comment: If you were submitting Word, wouldn't you have to make separate files? LaTeX doesn't seem at any particular disadvantage here, except that it is easier to split the resulting file.

Comment: What does `article` do with the options `a4j`?

Comment: @cfr, I know what you are saying about two files, and my advisor would probably be overjoyed if I told her we switch to word. However, I prefer LaTeX, as I have the burden of the formulas, tables, figures, typesetting and ensuring everything appears correctly in the final product (so no cut figures, split tables, orphaned sentences, hanging paragraphs, missed par indent, etc., you obviously understand the pain). Combine this with versioning, and the bewildering number of files LaTeX build produces (from prof's point of view), 2 files is probably the feather that broke the camel's back...

Comment: @cfr, another contributer to the project added the `a4j`, (and a lot of other needless packages for math typesetting) it exists out of courtesy, it'll be gone in the final version (when all agree we cannot do better or we are out of time), along with the other things.

Comment: Windows surely cannot manage  bash scripts but long time ago existed the .bat scripts (may be still, I have no idea, I admit) and you can use `\immediate\write18{} `to launch external programs. Anyway, what I would do is only one  PDF (with page counter reset at References and without and this chapter  to the table of contents), then split the PDF with pdftk or similar tools  (surely there are dozens for Windows) or simply print each part as PDF file.

Comment: You could write a small luascript which does the necessary calls. Your professor would then have to call it with texlua.

Comment: Is it an option to keep the bibliography in the main file while writing/discussing/sharing the proposal, and split it manually (with pdftk or similar) only at the end when the final proposal is submitted to the grant agency, and only by the person that is submitting it (presumably you, so your professor doesn't have to bother)?